# GIMP Script-fu Documentation

Tags: gimp, script-fu

I know how to access the procedure browser, but I'd like to know if there's any documentation for script parameter types or things like DIR-SEPARATOR which I can't find anywhere. It's silly that I have to check [this tutorial](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-script-fu-tutorial-first-script.html) to find a list of SF- parameters.

I'm trying to check if [DIR-MAKE](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/541) was actually added to GIMP, but short of attempting to use it in a script, I have no way to check this or any other "dir-" command. Googling "GIMP script-fu documentation" just brings up the little tutorial I linked to above and no actual documentation.

Comment: I don't use Scheme but I would expect it to have a general mechanism to tell if a string exists as a variable/function/constant, so maybe you should ask a more general question tagged "Scheme" or "Lisp". Otherwise you can get the Gimp version with `(gimp-version)` and check it against a known level. Also, if you write your Gimp scripts in Python, you can use all the native Python API for filesystems.

Comment: The SF- parameters for registering a function are specific to GIMP. I would have the same question about documentation for the equivalent PF_ parameters for Python as I can only find [this](https://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html) which is even less useful than the tutorial for script-fu I linked to above being that it's just a list of params. I'm not sure what you mean by 'checking against a known level'.

Comment: "The SF- parameters for registering a function are specific to GIMP". Yes but the way to tell if they are present in your version may not be. In Python I can check for the existence of constants using `if "variable_name" in globals()` which is the general Python way.

Comment: "'checking against a known level'" if you know that some feature is only available in 2.10.28 or later, you can check that your `(gimp-version)` is equal to or later than `2.10.28`.

Comment: I guess the answer to my original question is that I check if dir-make exists in my current version of GIMP by using `(procedure? dir-make)` in the console, but this will only return #t, no documentation about the procedure itself and it doesn't show up in the procedure browser because it's, as I've been told, "built into GIMP". And for things like SF-STRING, I'm not rightly sure what these even are, some sort of parameter for registering a script-fu function. I don't know how I would check those in the console. `if "PF_STRING" in globals()` returns a syntax error in the python-fu console.